error 0xc0000005 when opening Android Studio
i am using Windows 7 64-bit  and have installed the latest version android studio. when I try to open it, I get the following error :
**studio64.exe - Application Error**
the application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000005). click Ok to close the application
I have already tried the following steps, but the issue persists:
cmd :
sfc/scannow
chkdsk


install net FrameWorke

install vc_redist

delete temp fils


Windows 7 is not supported: A computer running a 64-bit version of Windows (8, 10, or 11) https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-install-android-studio#0
